# Is the first occurrence of a variable bound?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$ \forall \color{red}x (P(\color{blue}x) \rightarrow Q(\color{blue}x)) $

The occurrences of x in blue are bound by the quantifier $ \forall $, would the occurrence of x in red also be bound to $\forall$?

Is the x in red part of the formula which is 'universally quantified' or is it a part of the universal quantification itself?

Comment: It is not really the occurence of a variable but it is part of the quantifier symbol. It is needed to mark what variable the quantifier bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable attached to the quantifier is considered part of the quantification and usually said to neither bound nor free; the concept of free vs. bound variables only applies to the formula that the quantifier has scope over. The variable that goes with the quantifier may be called a *binding* variable.

Answer (score 1):

The red $x$ tells which symbol the quantifier is affecting.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1455962)

Comment: @Integrand I disagree. This *does* answer the question, though it would be clearer if it said "the red $x$ is neither free nor bound, it just tells which symbol the quantifier is affecting.

Comment: @AlexKruckman On page 7 (Title: Bound occurrence 1) of this PDF it defines it as bound - http://www.math.helsinki.fi/logic/opetus/log1/18_Logic_Predicate_Logic_free_bound_text.pdf . I'm unsure which it is now.